# How i can disable Scroll on Content inside of two scrollview

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview

I have Question is i want to disable scroll of one item from inside two scroll view like as

```
<ScrollView horizontal={true}>    ////Horizontal ScrollView
  <ScrollView>                     ////Vertical ScrollView
    <View />            //// View 1
    <View />           //// View 2
  </ScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

i just want to apply only Vertical scrollView on view 1 not Horizontal

Any one help me how i can achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found an answer, we can handle it with ref , check for demo link
https://snack.expo.dev/@mirza009/table

Answer (score 0):

please use this for disable scrolling

scrollEnabled={false}

Comment: bro i just want to remove View 1 from horizontal scroll view ,and vertical scrollview will apply on it, this props will disable overall scrollview on centent.

Comment: can you able to show ui ? then please share it so I can get the idea

Comment: UI it look like as Table  top and left header data, when the user vertical scroll the top header will sticky and when user horizontal scroll then left header will sticky, 
Its Main overView.

Comment: @mirzahayat please use createMaterialTopTabNavigator function of react-navigation or any materialtoptabbar for tab check this link as well https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/